# Calculus: When do we use this rule? $\left[u\left(x\right)^n\right]'=n\:u\left(x\right)^{\left(n-1\right)}\:\cdot \:u'\left(x\right)$

Tags: calculus

If we want to solve the following question: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2x-1}}\right)$$ Then we will have to use this following rule (the power rule), which seems strange to me since using the power rule for other equations doesn't require the same step to be performed when using this equation, which is: $$\left[u\left(x\right)^n\right]'=n \:u\left(x\right)^{\left(n-1\right)}\:\cdot \:u'\left(x\right)$$

So to summarize my question, when do we use this rule and why do we do so? (Couldn't fit the question into the title bar because it was long)

Comment: You forgot the $n$ out front.

Comment: You use that equality whenever you need to. What other sort of answer do you expect?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez the question is how do I know when if so?

Comment: Well, whenever you need to compute the derivative of the power of a function, use the formula for the derivative of the power of a function!

Comment: But usually we would use the common power rule and not this one..

Comment: In fact, what you wrote is simple the special case of the chain rule for the composition $h(u(x))$ with $h(x)=x^n$.

Comment: You will have to explain what you mean by "the commong power rule" and in what way it difers from the equality you wrote in the question (provided you correct the latter with the missing $n$, of course, as Randall observed in the first comment)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ok, that I didn't know since I am trying to do Math self taught therefore I did not come across the explanation to this situation.

Comment: @Randall I am new to this, so please enlighten me about which $n$ you were speaking about.

Comment: You wrote a formula for the derivative of something: does it work when $u(x)=x$?

Comment: In this application of the chain rule the exponent comes down as a coefficient.  The derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$ not $x$.

Comment: @Randall I am aware of how to use the power function, but if you try to solve questions in the description this method doesn't give the right answer..

Comment: Maybe it doesn’t work because the $n$ is missing.

Comment: @YuriyS OMG! I missed that while typing the equation here, but still I haven't figured out when to use that rule..

Comment: @Randall Just noticed what I had done as a mistake, thanks for correcting me on that one. But do you mind explaining when we use this rule?

Comment: Maybe you could show your workings for the example you mention here, and we could point out the issue with your solution?

Comment: @YuriyS Aha, since the one provided in the book I read mentioned using first part of the equation without *u'(x)

Comment: @YuriyS I'll do that in the morning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see the problem. Your problem is with the $'$ notation. Let's use another:

$$\frac{du^n(x)}{dx}=n u^{n-1}(x)\frac{du(x)}{dx}$$

Now if instead you were taking an $u$ derivative:

$$\frac{du^n}{du}=n u^{n-1}\frac{du}{du}=n u^{n-1}$$

It all depends on the variable you are differentiating with respect to.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, that actually solved my problem!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

In general, 
$$
f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)
$$
by the chain rule. You are asking about the case when $f(x)=x^n$.